# Limit HTML Text to 500 characters

Tags: php, html, text, limit

I have the following code that limits a html text to 500 characters:

```
if (strlen($text)>500) {
   $message = substr($text, 0, 500);
   echo $message;
}
else {
   echo $text;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the code cuts in the middle of the tag, so the output is:

```
...............................................Some text <a hre
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you really want users to input html tags ?

Comment: The question is, what is the expected output in such a case.  You may strip all the tags. You may cut out the last tag and use some kind of HTML Tidy.

Comment: The question is: Why would you limit such input to 500? If you expect your users to write decent HTML, they should also be smart enought to know the proper length of what they are inputting. If it's about storage, you can make text fields in databases virtually unlimited with little overhead (unless the users are actually stashing gigabites of text in there).

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, I don't see how this is feasible - not that it can't be done, but what if a `<span>` in `$text` requires more than 500 chars? Are you gonna expand the limit? I think the only option is to limit the input on the way in so the user knows to keep it short.

Comment: But if you need to have this limit, the proper way to solve this would be to not allow the long text at all instead of truncating it. So, on posting, just present the same form again, with the text that is too long, so they can fix it. Then, to help them a little more, you can apply the `maxlength` attribute to the textarea. And after that, help them even more, by adding a small script that shows the remaining characters, like below this comment box. If that script is smart, it will remove the attribute as well, so users can paste longer texts, and edit it in the text area.

Comment: This is just part of my script. My full script fetches topics from my IPB Board, then converts the BBCode to HTML, but I only want to show the first 500 characters of the converted HTML.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't show HTML at all. Just call [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the content, before limiting the length to 500.

Comment: I will use strip_tags, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be not to cut the message. So how can you limit the message?
Answer: Limit it by CSS.

```
echo '<div style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:300px;">'.$message.'</div>';
```

Now your message is not being displayed fully , but only a part of it and no tags are being stripped off, so no such errors.

Comment: But, if you have html text 10.000 characters per post, you need to limit. Not hiding it.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to strip off the inner data of html, not the html tags. Checkout http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for that. If any plaintext (i.e. inner content of html) is greater than a certain limit, you can shorten it (i.e. delete it) easily using that include.